# How to normalize URL's in an Angular app to resolve correctly when the app is "self hosted" or "integrated"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular5, angular7

In this question "integrated" refers to an angular app invoked from some path within another web app, whereas, "self hosted" refers to running from a tools such as VS Code using the `ng serve  --open` command where the root url is set to the src folder.

In MVC there are directives such as `Url.Action()` and `Url.Conntent()` that can be used to normalize relative pathing at any location within the app.

I have been reading about APP_BASE_REF, however, I don't think that will work. Is it possible to use a mechanism that would allow a similar construct as  --> `<img ng-fromAppRoot('~/assets/my.png')>`.

Also, in css constructs such as `background:url("~/assets/my.png")` will work in "integrated" but not "self hosted" and vice/versa.

Passing the root url in as part of the app initializer when "Integerated" may be part of the solution.

How is this usually handled, I am looking for a solution that will not require code changes to switch between debug/release?

Comment: I never tried this but I think you can solve this by ng build --base-href  however any asset required in angular that is not in the angular project  will probably need full path

Comment: I would only be concerned with loading assets within the context of the app. I will try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about nice URLs, you can use `HashLocationStrategy` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy)) and remove base url all together. Just use relative links to your assets like `<img src="assets/logo.svg">`.

If you need nice URLs, then you should make your own function which will work like `Url.Action()` and `Url.Content()` you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for giving direction.